# Trying to install pymc on Anaconda(python) in Windows 7 and getting weird error?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, pymc

I want to run some data science algorithms using Markov Chain Monte Carlo for Bayesian analysis and am trying to install PyMC but am frustratingly getting this error...

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py", line 333, in get_libraries
raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
NotImplementedError: Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64
```

Why would this happen and what can I do to solve it that doesnt require me hacking up python and apparently numpy that might screw other things up at a later time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out if I just go to the line in question ...

```
"C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py"
```

and comment out the statement so it looks like this -

```
else:
    pass #raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
```

PyMC compiles just fine.

Comment: Strange...I thought Stack Overflow deleted this question cus I cud never find it.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Leon's answer, in my case it seems the problem was that my default Fortran compiler was `mingw32` when `gnu.py` was expecting `msvc`. For PyMC's purposes `mingw32` works fine, so if you'd prefer to weaken the conditional rather than eliminate it entirely, replace

```
        if c_compiler and c_compiler.compiler_type == "msvc":
            return []
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
```

in `gnu.py` with

```
        if c_compiler and c_compiler.compiler_type in ["msvc", "mingw32"]:
            return []
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
```