# gfortran compiler for the scikits.bvp_solver

Tags: python, scientific-computing

my version for the Enthought Canopy python is 2.7.6, 64-bit. I am trying to install the scikits.bvp_solver on a windows 8.1 device by following the [tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/scikits.bvp_solver/index.html).

I have the easy_install ready, and downloaded the MinGW with gfortran([here](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran)), I tried both versions `gcc-5.1.0-64.exe`, and `gcc-5.1.0-32.exe`.

Then I proceeded to the second step, namely compiling from source using `python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install`, the error message from cmd is

> File "c:\users\xxx\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\
>   numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py", line 337, in get_libraries raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64
>   ")
>
> NotImplementedError: Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64

the system path I specify is `C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`, `C:\Rtool\gcc-4.6.3\libexec\gcc\x86_64-pc-mingw32\5.1.0`.

As someone in the google group mentioned to me that this should be a issue related to `numpy` and I should take a look of this [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126132/trying-to-install-pymc-on-anacondapython-in-windows-7-and-getting-weird-error), my error code is almost the same as his. But I do not figure out how him resolved his issue. So any comments are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, if you did not  already, get the package for scikits.bvp_solver as well. They recommended easy_install at  [the tutorial link for scikits.bvp_solver](http://pythonhosted.org/scikits.bvp_solver/tutorial.html) but you may have to set easy_install up as well depending on your python configuration.

Next, choose the 64-bit or  32-bit mingw gfortran compiler  to match based on if your python distribution is 64 or 32 bit.

Next, Are you sure you specified the path to the setup.py file correctly?

Either

1) cd to the directory containing setup.py (this may vary on your system, the example C:\directory_where_it_is below is just a placeholder)

> cd C:\directory_where_it_is

before typing,

> python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32
>   install

or

2) Specify the directory where setup.py is in the command line if running the prompt from some other directory

> python C:\directory_where_it_is\setup.py config --compiler=mingw32
>   build 
>   --compiler=mingw32 install

Finally it may be necessary to simply comment out the code for that exception in setup.py and attempt the build, in a similar way to the procedure [in this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126132/trying-to-install-pymc-on-anacondapython-in-windows-7-and-getting-weird-error)

Comment: thanks a lot. Since I only installed the `gcc-5.1.0-64.exe`, how am I supposed to find the setup.py file, how it comes from?

Comment: I get the setup.py from the package, and followed your instructions, then I received the error message `NotImplementedError:only ms compiler supported with gfortran on win64`. do you have any idea? I have the `MinGW with gfortran` installed, and it is in my system path.

Comment: I tried to 32-bit version, but I received the same error message.

Comment: I revise my post, and provide more information, if you can take a look, I will be very appreciated. thanks

Comment: I was mistaken you need the 64-bit gfortran if you are using 64-bit Python. But I can't duplicate your environment , not sure I can be of much more help.

Comment: thanks anyway. someone suggests me to read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126132/trying-to-install-pymc-on-anacondapython-in-windows-7-and-getting-weird-error), and I find my error message is exactly the same as his. Unfortunately, I can not understand how he resolved the issue in his post. Do you have any idea then?

Comment: I was going to suggest that but wasn't sure it would work for you since I couldn't duplicate your environment. Have added to answer.